# plot a nested list as multiple trendlines in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphing, trendline

I have a nested list:

```
nested=[[35,36,37],[34,35,36,37,38],[22,23,23,24]]
```

I need to create a graph where each sublist is a trendline in the same plot.For example, in (x,y) format: trendline 1 has points (1,35),(2,36),(3,37). trendline 2 has points (1,34),(2,35)...(5,38) and the same for the third trendline and I have no clue how to do this. I am a beginner in python, thank you very much for the advice!

edit I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for list in nested:
      x=range(1, len(list)+1)
      y=list
      plt.plot(x,y)
      plt.show()
```

This works, but gives numerous plots. I need to put it all in one plot

Comment: have you tried `[plt.plot(x) for x in nested]; plt.show()`?

Comment: If you want the x-axis values to start at 1, then you can try `[plt.plot(*m) for m in [list(zip(*[(ix+1,y) for ix,y in enumerate(x)])) for x in nested]]; plt.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the x-values by iterating through each sublist and using `enumerate` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nested = [[35,36,37],[34,35,36,37,38],[22,23,23,24]]
fully_nested = [list(zip(*[(ix+1,y) for ix,y in enumerate(x)])) for x in nested]
names = ['sublist%d'%(i+1) for i in range(len(fully_nested))]

for l in fully_nested:
    plt.plot(*l)
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.xlabel("Indices")
plt.ylim(0,40)
plt.xlabel("Values")
plt.legend(names, fontsize=7, loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()
```

This yields:

[image]

I hope this proves useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `plt.show()` outside the loop, otherwise it will show a plot on every iteration.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nested=[[35,36,37],[34,35,36,37,38],[22,23,23,24]]
for y in nested:
      x=range(1, len(y)+1)
      plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

(Also, don't use `list` as a variable name in python, because it is a datatype. While this does not cause harm here, it may produce complete chaos in other scenarios.)