# Plotting Nested Lists in Matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, nested-lists

I'm trying to plot nested lists as separate lines in matplotlib, but my x and y coordinates are in the nested list.

`List = [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [5, 7], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [8, 8], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [8, 8], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [16, 5], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [20, 9], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [4, 8], [20, 9], [16, 5], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [10, 11], [0, 0]]]`

Each of the nested lists is its own line and each of the nested lists is a coordinate.

I tried using the code from this post: [plot a nested list as multiple trendlines in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015074/plot-a-nested-list-as-multiple-trendlines-in-python), But it did not work.

Comment: Do one of the solutions answer your question? If so, you can accept an answer by clicking on the gray check next to the solution. If not, please clarify what remains an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each of the lines and then extract the x and y data individually to plot. I did the extraction using list comprehension. You could also do it using numpy.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

data = [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], 
        [[0, 0], [0, 0]], 
        [[0, 0], [0, 0]], 
        [[0, 0], [5, 7], [0, 0]], 
        [[0, 0], [8, 8], [0, 0]], 
        [[0, 0], [8, 8], [0, 0]], 
        [[0, 0], [16, 5], [0, 0]],
        [[0, 0], [20, 9], [0, 0]], 
        [[0, 0], [4, 8], [20, 9], [16, 5], [0, 0]],
        [[0, 0], [10, 11], [0, 0]]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for n, line in enumerate(data):
    x = [_line[0] for _line in line]
    y = [_line[1] for _line in line]
    ax.plot(x, y, label=n)
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Without list comprehensions: `ax.plot(*zip(*line), label=n)` ;)

Comment: @mozway Interesting, I didn't think of that. Does `*line` separate the inner list into the first and second indices?

Comment: No, `zip` does that. `*line` expands all sublists as individual parameters: `zip(*line)` -> `zip(*[[0, 0], [5, 7], [0, 0]])` -> `zip([0, 0], [5, 7], [0, 0])` -> `([0, 5, 0], [0, 7, 0])`, which we then expand again as parameters of `plot`: (`plot([0, 5, 0], [0, 7, 0])`)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `np.array`, see below.  Also, try to avoid naming lists "List", as it is a datatype and can become problematic later down the line!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Lists = [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [5, 7], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [8, 8], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [8, 8], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [16, 5], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [20, 9], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [4, 8], [20, 9], [16, 5], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [10, 11], [0, 0]]]
xcords = []
ycords = []

for i in range(len(Lists)): # ie, [[0,0],[0,0]]
    x = []
    y = []
    for j in range(len(Lists[i])): # ie, [0,0]
        x.append(Lists[i][j][0])
        y.append(Lists[i][j][1])
    xcords.append(x)
    ycords.append(y)

#Now you have xcords and ycords, corresponding lists of lists wherein each sublist makes up a line
print("x:", xcords, "y:", ycords)

xarrays = []
yarrays = []

for k in range(len(xcords)):    #ie, [0, 0]
    xarrays.append(np.array(xcords[k]))
    yarrays.append(np.array(ycords[k]))
    
#See comment below from Jarad 
for i in range(len(xarrays)):
    plt.plot(xarrays[i], yarrays[i])
plt.show()
```

[image: Image of matplotlib plots]

This code could be simplified further, but I hope it proves a useful starting point.

Comment: You can generalize the last line by using a `for` loop: `for i in range(len(xarrays)): plt.plot(xarrays[i], yarrays[i])`. That said, this solution is a bit overcomplicated for the problem at hand.

Comment: Also, the matplotlib import is typically written as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.